# I would like to know the translation of the writing on this ink stamp, to English please

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

From the research I've found on many websites, this trinket is an antique Chinese ink stamp/seal. It's included with what looks to be a writing utensil. The attached writing utensil is all the same metal and all solid. The stamp is about 2 inches wide (utensil included) and about 1 and a half inches high. It feels heavy in weight. My assumption of metal is brass, copper, or bronze. It has little to no damage or erosion, just some smudges. It has the English letters "CHIN", which I'm assuming meant to be "China" writen on the side of it and lastly the very bottom has Chinese writing.

[image]

Comment: Is this the original photo, or is it mirrored?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I've just consulted a friend. The stamp has 2 characters on it: 周寿, pronounced as zhōu shòu (modern Pinyin), or chou shou (Wade-Giles romanization). The characters are mirrored, so I made this image. Note that in Chinese seal cutting, the reading order is generally from right to left:

[image: The two characters]

Obviously this is not a Chinese word, so must be the name of a person. Also this piece is slightly flawed, because the bottom part of the character 周 is wrongly inscribed.

Comment: 上面的回答讲的非常有道理，但是我认为这个"周"字是因为是篆体才这样写的，而不是写错了。 translate The above answer is very reasonable, but I think the word "周" is written in this way because it is a seal script, rather than a mistake.